# How to add visual displays (graphs, screens, diagrams) to Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, display, diagram, graphing

I'm having a lot of fun with C#, recently I created a simple "statistics calculator". It takes in data and calculates the mean, standard deviation etc.

However, I want to add something visual to my console apps. For example a diagram showing the data, or a graph (I also want to try coding something with function graphing).

How can I do that?

Comment: Console alone is really limited in terms of nice graphics. Consider upgrading at least to Winforms, which has the MSChart control..

Comment: It is recommended that you use winform to make charts or charts to display data, because it is difficult to achieve graphical processing due to the limitations of console applications. Winform comes with related controls, which can well meet your requirements.Please read the answers below and give some updates to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what visual technology you use – WinForms, WPF, MAUI, etc. WinForms has the built-in [Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.8) class. But I think you will eventually want to explore other, 3rd party solutions. I used the [LiveCharts](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2) with WPF. It is not that hard to prepare data and the graphs look nice.

Answer (score 0):

For GUI with .Net there are many options including:

- Web: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/
- Desktop :
  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/desktop ,
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/desktop/wpf/get-started/create-app-visual-studio?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=netdesktop-6.0
- Multi-Platform: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui , https://www.avaloniaui.net/